# Angle of rotation by pure unit quaternions(fundamental unit quaternions)

Tags: abstract-algebra, vectors, quaternions

From the versor definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor), i understand that versor is a unit quaternion and also a pure quaternion with its scalar part zero. So, versor is a pure unit quaternion.

I think that fundamental quaternion units $i,j,k$  are also versors(!).

From the angle-axis notation $\mathbf {q} =\mathbf cos(\alpha/2) + sin(\alpha/2) \vec{v} $.

To get a pure quaternion, we need a $0$ for cosinus part. For $cos(\alpha/2)=0$ we could use $\alpha=180$ so $sin(90)=1$. So, if we have $q=i$ then we could say its a 180 degrees rotation.

Are there anything wrong with this?

Comment: I'd take $\alpha$ to be $\pi$ actually. For example, $q\mapsto iqi^{-1}$ is a rotation of $\pi$ radians on the space of pure quaternions. It's an **instructive** exercise to demonstrate this explicitly.

Comment: So how could we do this? By starting with Rodrigues formula and compare the results with Quaternion rotation formula?

Comment: You could see my comment on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828434/proof-of-rotation-by-pure-unit-quaternions

Comment: So isn't my proof correct given in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof: $i,j,k$ are 180 degrees rotation around the axis defined by them.

1. Fundamental quaternion units are versors by definition. [Versors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor) are pure unit quaternions.
2. The angle-axis notation of a quaternion $\mathbf {q} =\mathbf cos(\alpha/2) + sin(\alpha/2) \vec{v} $.
3. To get a pure quaternion, we need a $0$ for cosinus part. For $cos(\alpha/2)=0$ we have $\alpha/2=90,270,...$  so $\alpha=180$ so $sin(90)=1$ we could take $\alpha=180$. So, if we have $q=i$ then we could say $i,j,k$ are 180 degrees($\pi$) rotation. $\blacksquare $